# read in csv file in R and make a list out of last column

Tags: r, csv

Content of my.csv

```
project names,task names
Build Finances,Calculate Earnings
Build Roads,Calculate Equipment Costs
Buy Food, Calculate Grocery Costs
```

The code I'm using to read `/tmp/my.csv` into a variable/vector is:

```
taskNamesAndprojectNames <- read.csv("/tmp/my.csv", header=TRUE)
```

What I want to do is to grab the last column of my.csv file which has been put into the csvContent variable.  And then make a list out of it.

So, something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript
taskNamesAndprojectNames <- read.csv("/tmp/my.csv", header=TRUE)
#str(tasklists)
#tasklists
#tasklists[,ncol(tasklists)]
taskNames <- list(taskNamesAndprojectNames[,-1])
typeof(taskNames)
length(taskNames)
```

The problem with the above code is, when i run `length` on the `taskNames` variable/vector to confirm that it has the correct number of items or elements, I only get a response of `1`.  Which is not accurate.

```
[roywell@test01 data]$ ~/readincsv.r 
[1] "list"
[1] 1
```

What am I doing wrong here?  Can someone help me correct this code?  What i want to do is grab the last column of an excel csv sheet, get the values in that last column and put them into a variable.  Make a list out of it.  Then iterate through the list to confirm that values/input provided by a user matches at least one of the elements in the list.

Comment: You are only looking for the last column right?

Comment: yes, thats correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`taskNames <- list(taskNamesAndprojectNames[,-1])` makes a list with one element that is a character vector of length 3.

It sounds like you are looking for a vector in this case:

```
taskNames <- taskNamesAndprojectNames[,-1]
typeof(taskNames)
[1] "character"

length(taskNames)
[1] 3
```